# Let $X(n,t) = nt \text{ for } n \in \Omega_1, t \in \Omega_2. \text{ Is } X \text{ } \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 \text{-measurable?}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1, \mathbb{P}_1) \text{ and } (\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$ be two random experiments. The first models the rolling of a fair die and the second the choosing of a number from the unit interval (0,1] (with uniform possibility). The information available in $\mathcal{F}_1$ allows one to decide whether the outcome is even whereas the information in $\mathcal{F}_2$ is able to decide only the first decimal place of the non-terminating decimal expansion of the number picked.

Let $X(n,t) = nt \text{ for } n \in \Omega_1, t \in \Omega_2. \text{ Is } X \text{ } \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 \text{-measurable?}$

I am leaning towards 'no' because even though each possible outcome of X can be traced back to an element of $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$, there can be multiple mappings from a single X to many elements of $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$. So although for every possible outcome on $\mathbb{R}$ CAN be traced to elements of $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ we can't say that an outcome X came from a PARTICULAR member of $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$.

Can someone please clarify for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: It is not necessary that $X$ be injective (one-to-one) to be measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}$. For each $n$, define $E_n = \{t\in \Omega_2:X(n,t)\in V\}$. Then $E_n\in \mathcal{F}_2$, so $\{n\}\times E_n \in \mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$. Hence $X^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_n \{n\}\times E_n$, $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$-measurable.